# Baking normal maps from compound high-poly models

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I learned how to bake normal maps and it's working well so far. My model is a simple oven to which I'd like to add some rivets. The model will be used in a game, so the rivets should only exist in the normal map.

I know how to do that by adding geometry to the high poly model, but if I later add some more parts to the low poly model, I think I have to redo the work of adding the rivets, or I have to also add the parts of the low poly model to the high poly one. I'd like to avoid this work and add geometry in a non-destructive way.

My question is: Can I add geometry to the high poly model as objects so I can move them, use the array modifier etc?

I tried to parent the rivets to the high poly model, but they are ignored in the baking process.[image: Oven with rivet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bake several objects into your lowpoly.

Simply select all of them, then maintain <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select your lowpoly. Make sure the lowpoly is outlined in yellow (meaning it is **Active**) while other objects are outlined in orange (meaning they're **Selected**).

In the baking options, check "**Selected to active**", and hit the "Bake" button.

*While many objects can be **selected** at the same time, only one can be **active**. It's usually the last selected object, and its name appears top left of the viewport.*

Comment: Ah, simple! Thank you so much, I struggled with this for hours!